Pyspark calculated column with lag i.e derived column of previous record
I see one of post in stack overflow, am also looking the same solution.
I think pyspark doesn't support the LAG on derived column of previous record. Please share if you find the solution.
column A.   Column B.     Column C.  Column D
=========.  ========      ========.  ========
1234.        202401.        123        A
1234         202402.        345.       null
1234         202403         50         null
Need to apply the LAG on top of Column C and Column D Columns
if LAG(Column C) > 75 and LAG(Column D) == 'A' then  Column D Value is 'A' Otherwise 'N'
Example:
df = df.withColumn("Column B", when((col("Column D").isNull()) & (lag("Column D").over(windowSpec) == "A") & (col("Column C") > 75),"N") .otherwise(df["Column D"]))
problem - only Second row is updating.. Not considering the previous derived column..

please put some lines of code to create a fictitious dataset to replicate your problem. Also put a snapshot or an example of output dataframe.
